# Security question - Google Sheet credentials.json access

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I have an outside developer who is asking for a credentials.json file in order to write to a Google Sheet.

I'd like to restrict the developer's access to just a single file, so I've made a service account with access to just that sheet. However, I'm quite unfamiliar with service accounts and the amount of access they allow. For example, it's unclear to me if the service account will have access to any files/scripts/processes outside of the single sheet shared with it and the API project in which it lives. Is there a way to check that? Or any documentation on best practices for granting this kind of access? (Or really, any kind of "Google APIs" for Dummies I could read.)

For context, I have basic programming experience, but top out at Javascript in AppScripts.

Comment: You can view the permissions that a service account has in the Google Cloud Console. Login, go to "IAM & Admin" -> IAM. Find the service account. Click the pencil icon on the right hand side and a dialog will pop up listing all the roles assigned. I recommend doing a Google Search on each role assigned to the service account so that you understand what permissions are granted. Read this article on Sharing and Permission in Google Sheets: https://help.tillerhq.com/en/articles/432685-sharing-and-permissions-in-google-sheets

Comment: This article should help also: https://denisluiz.medium.com/python-with-google-sheets-service-account-step-by-step-8f74c26ed28e